# Read File records from remote file using camel kafka connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

Which camel kafka connector component can read a file from remote server and publish records to a kafka topic? I tried camel-sftp-kafka-connector but its moving whole file to topic. Any connector which can read file on remote server directly?

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS DEPENDENY

```
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
      </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    String topicName = "topic=javainuse-topic";
    String kafkaServer = "kafka:localhost:9092";
    String zooKeeperHost = "zookeeperHost=localhost&zookeeperPort=2181";
    String serializerClass = "serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder";

    String toKafka = new StringBuilder().append(kafkaServer).append("?").append(topicName).append("&")
            .append(zooKeeperHost).append("&").append(serializerClass).toString();

    from("file:C:/publicUpload?noop=true").split().tokenize("\n").to(toKafka);
}
```

}